# Scaling fonts with different screensizes

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to scale my fonts so that they look the same on different screen sizes, large or small. I have the code below, which is linked to an underlying theme (flutter standard theme). I have tried manually changing the fontsize but this does not help since it looks different on all screen sizes.

Is there a recommended way to auto-scale fontsize depending on screen size?

```
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/50)),
              Text("We're finding your pizza!",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: theme.textTheme.title.copyWith(fontSize: 26),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40)),
              Text(
                  "We'll notify you when we've found one.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: theme.textTheme.title),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40)),
              Text(
                  "Estimated wait time:",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: theme.textTheme.title),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/80)),
              Text(
                  "< 1 minute.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: theme.textTheme.title,
              )],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)

**Installing**

add this to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
```

**Usage**

```
AutoSizeText(
 'Your auto size text',
 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),//minimum font size
 maxLines: 2,//if needed
)
```